# ip address resolves to localhost from virtualbox hosted apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualbox

Apache keeps resolving or redirecting? to `localhost`.

The assigned ip `192.168.0.145` resolves/redirects to `localhost` on any machine in the LAN.

What would cause this?

## Details:

I have apache running on virtualbox with a bridged connection.

If I try in virtualbox the site is served.

```
ifconfig && nmap 192.168.0.145 && ufw status && cat /etc/hosts && telnet 192.168.0.145 80
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:5c:db:ba  
          inet addr:192.168.0.145  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe5c:dbba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8579694 (8.5 MB)  TX bytes:836980 (836.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:469630 (469.6 KB)  TX bytes:469630 (469.6 KB)


Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-25 20:31 CDT
Nmap scan report for jimjamshimshams.com (192.168.0.145)
Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   bob-VirtualBox
192.168.0.145   jimjamshimshams.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Trying 192.168.0.145...
Connected to 192.168.0.145.
Escape character is '^]'.
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And `netstat -tlnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1019/apache2    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1051/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      726/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      726/cupsd
```

`access.log` after attempting to connect from another computer on the LAN:

```
192.168.0.119 - - [25/Sep/2014:20:55:19 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 341 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
192.168.0.119 - - [25/Sep/2014:20:56:55 -0500] "help" 302 0 "-" "-"
192.168.0.119 - - [25/Sep/2014:20:59:34 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 341 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

`apache2ctl -S` :

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 192.168.0.145 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 192.168.0.145 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it out.

This line from the `access.log` is what cued me in:

```
192.168.0.119 - - [25/Sep/2014:20:56:55 -0500] "help" 302 0 "-" "-"
```

Apache was being redirected by the application that I was trying to install ( Magento ).

I had to edit the `base_url` in the database, because it was set to `localhost`.